# Function onExit not triggering while navigating

Tags: sapui5

While navigating from one screen to another onExit has to be called to free resources. However it is not triggered. This is my code:

```
function (BaseController, JSONModel, formatter, Filter, FilterOperator) {
    "use strict";

    return BaseController.extend("app.controller.Worklist", {

        _oCatalog: null,
        _oResourceBundle: null,

        onInit: function() {
            this._oView = this.getView();           
        },

        onThirdScreen : function (oEvent) {
            this.getRouter().navTo("thirdscreen", {});
        },

        onExit: function() {
            if (this._Dialog) {
                this._Dialog.destroy(true);
            }
        }

    });         

});
```

Answer (score 3):

As @mattbtt has mentioned, views are not destroyed each time you switch to another view so the "exit" event will not be triggered. What you can do, however, is to handle the onBeforeHide/onAfterHide events from the view instead.

```
onInit: function() {
    this._oView = this.getView();           
    this._oView.addEventDelegate({
        onBeforeHide: function(oEvent) {
            debugger;
        },

        onAfterHide: function(oEvent) {
            debugger;
        }
    }, this)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response.. if onexit not triggered ...then how to free resources like fragments..so i can use in navigated view without duplicateid

Comment: @anilkumar There is no need to destroy the fragment explicitly since it will be destroyed together when the parent gets destroyed. If you encounter _duplicated ID_ issue, analyze where you're creating that fragment without checking if it's already created.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior as navigating via the routing mechanism does **not** destroy the corresponding view. This makes a lot of sense as views normally do not change during the lifespan of their parent component. Furthermore it would slow down the application if views need to be repeatedly instantiated if the corresponding route matches.

Comment: Thank you for response.. if onexit not triggered ...then how to free resources like fragments..so i can use in navigated view without duplicateid.

Comment: Destroying fragments in onExit is okay. If you have duplicate id issues you have another problem. Maybe you extend your question with the relevant details.

Comment: onexit is not triggering ...if i place fragment destroy in onexit will it free resource

Comment: You have another problem, when you need to destroy your fragment when you navigate! In general you should free ressources in onExit (when your component is destroyed) not when you navigate between views. Please extend the question with the problem you get or accept the answer and open a detail question regarding your duplicate id issue.